# Swing - GridLayout components not filling up all available space

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, grid-layout

I've done a search of StackOverflow but all of the questions seem to ask the exact opposite of my problem.

I'm writing code that dynamically adds `JLabels` to a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`, all contained within a `JScrollPane`. Here's an SSCCE:

```
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
static Test window;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                window = new Test();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            EventQueue.invokeAndWait (new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
                    label.setSize(160, 40);
                    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    // Finalise GUI
                    window.panel.add(label);
                    window.panel.revalidate();
                    window.panel.repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public Test() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 200);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));

    final JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
    outerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    outerPanel.add(panel);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outerPanel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setBounds(12, 0, 460, 160);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
}
```

From my understanding, in `GridLayouts`, "each component takes all the available space within its cell." Yet here, the `JLabels` don't actually take up all the available space in the `JPanel`.

I'm not sure where my mistake is. Is it in the `GridLayout` or in the surrounding `Components` not giving the `GridLayout` enough space?

Thanks all.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Especially with this `Thread.sleep(100);` called on the Swing event thread??

Comment: See edits to answer please

Comment: `Thread.sleep(100);` was just there so I could see the JLabels being added one by one while keeping the code short.

Comment: Again, that's dangerous code. If you want to see them added, use the Swing Timer as demonstrated below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JLabels **are** taking all available space. It's your JPanel that's small. Test it yourself with a Border:

```
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));

    // **** add this to see ****
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
```

If you want the labels to fill out the top, then use a different layout for the outer panel. Note changes marked with the `// !!` comment:

```
    final JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
    // !! outerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    outerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // !!
    // !! outerPanel.add(panel);
    outerPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); // !!
```

Also that `Thread.sleep(...)` is dangerous code in a Swing GUI. If you want a delay in adding components, use the best Swing tool for the job: a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). For example

```
    final int timerDelay = 100;
    final int maxLabelCount = 100; 
    new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
        private int labelCount = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (labelCount < maxLabelCount) {
                final JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
                // !! label.setSize(160, 40); // NO!
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                // Finalise GUI
                window.panel.add(label);
                window.panel.revalidate();
                window.panel.repaint();
            } else {
                // stop this timer
                ((Timer) evt.getSource()).stop();
            }
            labelCount++;
        }
    }).start();
```